# What is a Shared Sumo?

Tags: india, terminology, overland

In the many places I have read about shared sumos.  For example:

> this is where you can get the **Shared Sumos** to 'Sohra'-the name Cherrapunjee goes by locally & officially.

What exactly is it and how it looks like? The link to the picture will be fine.
I have tried to google it, but have not found good results.

Comment: Perhaps [Isuzu Sumo](http://www.automobilrevue.cz/rubriky/truck-bus/predstavujeme/isuzu-sumo-n-75-190m-do-silne-konkurence_39761.html)?

Comment: I don't think so. It is a trucks in Czech Republic. I am searching cars for people in India :)

Comment: The name Sumo is used in some other countries. But Dorothy's answer probably says I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [How to get from Guwahati to Shillong and Cherrapunjee](https://www.lostwithpurpose.com/guwahati-shillong-cherrapunjee/) April 25, 2017, blog includes this image:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A "Sumo" is a model of car/SUV by the Indian car manufacturer "Tata".

See [Tata Motors - Sumo Gold](http://www.tatamotors.com/product/sumo-gold/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A shared sumo is like a bunch of people sharing the taxi fare together. In some rural areas,this is the only public service available. Going alone in  a taxi would cost 100-150. People share this fare by paying 10-20 per head. The rates i mentioned are just an example and they may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest that shared Sumo be treated as a generic term same as a shared taxi, where you share the ride with several other passengers on a pre-determined route for a set fee. The vehicle itself could be any of the many many MUVs available in India. Like below:

[image: Force Trax]
[image: Maruti Eeco]
[image: Rhino]
[image: Mahindra Xylo]
[image: Toyota Qualis]
[image: Mahindra Bolero]
[image: Maruti Omni]
[image: Tata Sumo]